# How to execute the same vi command in sublime text 3?

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

I want to insert 8 blank spaces at the beginning of lines from 8 till 13 in the following file.

[image]

It is simple to do the job in vi,just type **`8,13s/^/        /g`** in command mode.

How to execute the same vi command **`8,13s/^/        /g`**   in sublime text 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of this as "inserting spaces," think of it as changing the level of indentation. Then use the indentation hotkeys.

Select lines 8 through 13, then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (macOS) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (Windows) until it is indented to the level you wish.

As you might guess, going in the other direction is the same, but you use <kbd>[</kbd> instead.

Comment: The key point is that can all kinds of vi  script be executed on sublime text 3 or just a small part of it ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature No vi script can be executed in Sublime Text. You can use a plugin to activate the vim keyboard mode, and you can get certain plugins that emulate certain vim features, but the general set of commands behind things like `:` and `s` are not implemented in vim-style in Sublime Text. Much of the same work can be accomplished, just not in the same ways.

Comment: Select lines 8 through 13, then press Cmd] (macOS) or Ctrl] (Windows or linux)